# Facebook Graph Api Friendlist Object

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I might be missing something, however I'm trying to get the feed for a friendlist object.

I'm currently grabbing the members of the friendlist object and appending them together in a json format.

[id,id,id]

I'm then using those source ids and sending them as args to the REST api's stream.get

This is returning me results however I can't help but feel I've over looked something.

Conclusion:
Dont do this, just don't do it, it's slow. Example a user w/ 300 users it will take forever to return.

Answer (score 3):

You can get very close to getting friends list feed with minimal effort by :

```
FBRequest *request=[FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/home?filter=fl_<friendListId>"];
```

where you replace  with actual friendList id.
You can obtain those by :

```
FBRequest *request=[FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/friendlists"];
```

I do realise that you probably have no need for this answer but I hope might help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the graph API (which I recommend as we are in the process of removing the REST API) you can retrieve the feed of multiple uids (after read_stream permission is granted) as such `https://graph.facebook.com/feed?ids=uid1,uid2,uid3&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`.

Comment: I'm assuming this will return the same results as going to facebook and using the friendlist filter there? Also is there a limit on the number of ids?

Comment: Switched to using posts, since = yesterday.

It's returning results slow but I guess I'll just have to deal with it.